# SQL Server Get last max timestamp from group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to return a single row per id and per date, which is the max/last value for that day - max/last value for a particular day is given by its time.
This is how much I got so far

```
select distinct a.AU_ID, MAX([DATE] + ' ' + [TIME]) as 'TIMESTAMPfull'
from TABLE_B b join TABLE_A a on a.AU_ID = b.AU_ID
where a.col like 'A%' and [DATE] BETWEEN 20210408 AND 20220408 and a.AU_ID = 'xxXXxx00001'
group by a.AU_ID, b.col1, b.col2, b.col3
```

Returns me this, as you can see for 20220111 this returns 5 rows, but i only need the one occured last on 20220111:

| AU_ID | TIMESTAMPfull |
| --- | --- |
| xxXXxx00001 | '20211104 061847 |
| xxXXxx00001 | '20220111 200012 |
| xxXXxx00001 | '20220111 200248 |
| xxXXxx00001 | '20220111 200902 |
| xxXXxx00001 | '20220111 201116 |
| xxXXxx00001 | '20220111 201317 |
| xxXXxx00001 | '20220205 090758 |

Goal is to return only 1 row per [DATE] --> row 6 from the table above for 20220111.
Expected result:

| AU_ID | TIMESTAMPfull |
| --- | --- |
| xxXXxx00001 | '20211104 061847 |
| xxXXxx00001 | '20220111 201317 |
| xxXXxx00001 | '20220205 090758 |

Comment: Only GROUP BY a.AU_ID.

Comment: which dbms? Also, please [edit] to include the expected results as text (not a screen shot).

Comment: [DATE] is nvarchar(8) and [TIME] nvarchar(6)

Comment: Thanks.  D-Shih beat me to it ;-) A partitioned row_number() should do the trick though. Here's a fiddle to see it in action https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bfbe147e38708d795a6f452a09e6946c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function in the subquery.

```
SELECT AU_ID,
       TIMESTAMPfull
FROM (
    SELECT a.AU_ID,
            [DATE] + ' ' + [TIME] TIMESTAMPfull,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [DATE], ORDER BY [TIME] DESC) rn
    FROM TABLE_B b 
    JOIN TABLE_A a on a.AU_ID = b.AU_ID
    WHERE a.col like 'A%' 
    AND [DATE] BETWEEN 20210408 AND 20220408
    AND a.AU_ID = 'xxXXxx00001'
) t1
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: did the trick - very nice - thanks D-Shih